# Leapfrog method in Particle-in-cell

Tags: computational-physics, simulations, software

Recently, I wanted to write a 3D electromagnetic Particle-in-cell code with C++. I know that I should use [leapfrog method](https://www.particleincell.com/2011/velocity-integration/), for example, when I calculate the position and velocity of particles，I should calculate according to the following order:

[image]

```
//firt move velocity back by 0.5dt
v = v - 0.5*q/m*E*dt;
//main loop
//update velocity and position
v = v + q/m*E*dt;
x = x + v*dt;
```

But when I want to write 3D PIC, I don't know the calculation order of $E,\,B,\,v,\,x$ (postion) and their formula. Can someone help me please?

Comment: I'd be inclined to ask on the [Computational Science SE](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I think the same method is valid - just calculate the 3 components of v instead of 1 when you get to the "calculate velocity" step; and the same for position. In other words - use vector quantities.

Comment: Floris is correct, the three dimensions are treated independently.

Comment: @Floris _ I am wondering if the question is more complicated - rather than just wanting position and velocity as vectors there is also the issue that $E$ and $B$ are determined from the positions of the charges and their velocities and, of course, determine the force on these particles.

Comment: I don't think this question is unclear. Nor does it fall afoul of the [computational questions policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5603).

Answer (score 1):

For any PIC simulation, you are necessarily tying yourself to *particles*, particles that experience *forces*. Thus, we have the generic force law:
\begin{align}
m_i\frac{d\mathbf v_i}{dt}&=\mathbf F_i  \tag{1a}\\
\frac{d\mathbf x_i}{dt}&=\mathbf v_i \tag{1b}
\end{align}
In the case of PIC, you are often considering the [*electromagnetic* (Lorentz) force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force#Equation_.28cgs_units.29), so the force on particle $i$ is,
$$
\mathbf F_i=q_i\left(\mathbf E+\boldsymbol\beta_i\times\mathbf B\right)\tag{2}
$$
with $\boldsymbol\beta=\mathbf v/c$. Since we've got particles, the electric and magnetic fields are defined as
$$
\mathbf E=\sum_{i\neq j}\frac{q_j}{r_{ij}^2}\hat{r}_j,\qquad\mathbf B=\sum_{j\neq i}\boldsymbol\beta_j\times\mathbf E
$$

You've already mentioned the leapfrog method, which is one of the more common methods for PIC simulations (at least to my knowledge). Your question is how/when to compute $\mathbf E,\,\mathbf B$. The answer is quite simple: *after you've computed $x$*; after all, the electric and magnetic fields are functions of *space*.

Note, though, that the magnetic field term of the Lorentz force (eq (2)) contains a velocity component; this must also be leapfrogged:
$$
\mathbf v^{n+1/2}_i\sim\frac12\left(\mathbf v_i^{n-1/2}+\mathbf v_i^{n+1/2}\right)\times\mathbf B
$$
which that $\mathbf v_i^{n+1/2}$ on the RHS makes it a little bit harder to solve (you'll likely need a linear algebra solver). There is an alternative, called the [Boris method](https://www.particleincell.com/2011/vxb-rotation/), that combines the velocity and electric field into a single term & you end up with a "rotation" without needing to involve the linear algebra solver needed; however, I am not well versed in this so I cannot say much beyond that.

Thus, the generic stepping algorithm would be something like,

```
while (t < tend)
   computeEMFields(x, v, E, B);
   newV = updateVelocity(v, E, B);
   newX = moveParticles(v, newV, x);
   computeDT();
   t = t + dt;
   x = newX
   v = newV
end while
```

Comment: Velocity (or position) Verlet methods are also useful here (also called Newmark methods in computational mechanics) -- these are related to the leapfrog method. Also, congrats on answering a question almost half-a-year after you left comments on it!

Comment: @tpg2114: Thank Community, it bumped it a bit ago & reminded me about it!